# Why doesn't my view slide up when the keyboard is shown?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I'm using the following Activity layout.

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
        android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        app:panelHeight="0dp"
        app:shadowHeight="0dp"
        app:overlay="true" >

        <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/rootRelativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/location"
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:layout="@layout/activity_main_map" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:theme="@style/toolbarThemeFakeDark"
                android:background="@drawable/trans_toolbar_bg"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:subtitle="test">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/wordmark"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/wordmarkwhite"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/wordmark" />
            </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/timeBar"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@drawable/trans_toolbar_bg"
                android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" >
                    <SeekBar
                        android:id="@+id/maxTime"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
                        android:progress="100"
                        android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"
                        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/timeNumber"
                        style="@style/MapSeekBar"
                        android:thumb="@drawable/map_seekbar_thumb" />

                    <TextView android:id="@+id/timeNumber"
                        android:background="@drawable/map_seekbar_thumb"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_width="32dp"
                        android:layout_height="32dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/cpb_grey"
                        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="0dp" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <!--- Where all the fragments live -->
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:elevation="20dp"/>
    </com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>

    <fragment android:name="com.myapp.FragmentLeftPanel"
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:maxWidth="400dp"
        />

    <fragment android:name="com.myapp.FragmentFilterPanel"
        android:id="@+id/right_drawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        />
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>

<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/cluster_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:elevation="20dp"/>
<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/cluster_event_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:elevation="20dp"/>
<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/create_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:elevation="20dp"/>
```

And the following fragment layout.

The fragment gets loaded into the "fragment_container" node of the activity layout.

```
<View android:id="@+id/backgroundColor"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/app_light_background"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/commentFrame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:background="@color/app_light_background" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/textBox"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="start|bottom|end"
                android:measureWithLargestChild="true"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/attachButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:elevation="1dp"
                    android:paddingStart="1dp"
                    android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                    android:contentDescription="Attach Picture"
                    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/commentBox"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="start|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="Comment"
                    android:inputType="text|textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
                    android:maxHeight="70dp"
                    android:autofillHints=""
                    android:textColor="@color/app_light_primary_text" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/sendButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:paddingStart="24dp"
                    android:paddingTop="8dp"
                    android:paddingEnd="8dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                    android:contentDescription="Post Comment"
                    android:tint="@color/app_light_primary_frame"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_send_grey600_36dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </FrameLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/commentFrame"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
                android:id="@+id/commentRefresh"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/commentList"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@color/app_light_background"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true" />
            </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/shadow_height"
            android:layout_above="@+id/commentFrame"
            android:background="@drawable/above_shadow" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:theme="@style/toolbarThemeFakeDark">
        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    </RelativeLayout>

<View android:id="@+id/backPart"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dip"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<View android:id="@+id/dragPart"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/backPart"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

My problem is the "commentBox" field in the fragment. When you tap on it, the virtual keyboard comes up over the top of the bottom half of the fragment content instead of pushing the content up. So you cannot see the text field as you type.

I've been searching and trying recommendations for days, such as using "android:windowSoftInputMode=adjustPan" or some variant. But none of them have had any effect.

What could be preventing the keyboard from pushing up the content of the Activity in this instance?

Comment: Could you try making Scrollview as your parentview. That should help.

Comment: As the parentview of what?

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustResize"` to the activity in your manifest file

And then add `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` in your rootLayout(not the EditText)

Comment: Thanks for that, but doing these things had no effect. I tried adding the 'fitsSystemWindows' line to the root fragment layout, then the root activity layout. Neither made a difference. Also tried adding it to both root layouts.